# Program gets terminated abruptly in Visual C++

Tags: c, visual-studio

Whwenever I try to execute this block of code it abruptly shuts down if I dont use the `getch()` function. Moreover I have tried different combinations of accepting and printing the string like `gets()` and `puts()` etc. My question is what causes this error and how can i remove this error?

```
void main()
{
  char str[100];
  printf("Enter your string\n");
  fgets(str,100,stdin);
  printf("%s",str);
  getch();
}
```

Comment: Try running the exe from a cmd session manually, then the output of the program will appear in the session and persist on screen after the program has exited.

Comment: You are just getting a preview of what happens when your user starts your program from a shortcut on the desktop.  Without the "press any key to continue" code, the exact same thing will happen.  Maybe you don't intend your user to run it from a shortcut and only from the command prompt, that's fine, just set a breakpoint on the last curly brace if you want to verify the output.  Best way of course is to make your program operate correctly either way, use GetConsoleProcessList().

Comment: Why attempt to print `str` without checking is `fgets()` succeeded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void main()
{
  char str[100];
  printf("Enter your string\n");
  fgets(str,100,stdin);
  printf("%s",str);
  getch();
}
```

You have many problems for a small program.

1. you are using `getch();` This requires you to `#include <conio.h>`
2. You are using `printf()` family functions. This requires you to `#include <stdio.h>`
3. The function prototype for `main()` has to be `int main(void)` in your case

In conclusion, this would be the fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main(void)
{
  char str[100];
  printf("Enter your string\n");
  fgets(str,100,stdin);
  printf("%s",str);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

run it from the cmd.exe command line window.

The reason it shuts down is because after completing everything in the program, the program automatically terminates. `Getch()` just makes the system wait for another input.

Comment: @AlterMann Fair enough, I edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Both the `include` statements you mentioned i have put it already before posting this question

Comment: @user5451270 Did you read the rest? If anything is still missing for you, what exactly are you still having problems with? Especially read the last paragraph on why you need getch() to make it not terminate.

Comment: Ya i read it, the problem is it's shutting down if i remove `getch()`. I actually have no use for `getch()` here. I am solely using it for the purpose of seeing my output which i can't see because the command terminal exists abruptly.

Comment: Can it be because of software problem with visual studio c++?

Comment: Ok I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

This  is the expected behaviour when you run and attach a debugger. Try running with *ctrl+f5*.